# "Derivative-like" Operator such that $H(f(x)^{g(x)}) = H(f(x))^{H(g(x))}$

Tags: derivatives, exponentiation, tetration

Given 2 functions $f(x),g(x)$ we have:
$$D(f(x)+g(x)) = D(f(x))+D(g(x))$$
And
$$D^*(f(x)g(x)) = D^*(f(x))D^*(g(x))$$ where $D^*$ is the multiplicative derivative: $$D^*(f(x)) = lim_{h\rightarrow 0} {\frac{f(x+h)}{f(x)}}^{1/h}$$

My question is whether there is another type of derivative $H$ such that $$H(f(x)^{g(x)}) = H(f(x))^{H(g(x))}$$

Comment: Is D() just the typical derivative? Or was that intended to be D*?

Comment: Yeah, D is just the derivative.

Comment: Do you have any other constraints for a "derivative"? If linearity is the only constraint, then I'm sure many limits would fit.

Comment: It should be a natural generalization to the above limit for exponentiation, I also believe that such a limit Would have a property something like: $H(f) = e^{D^*{(f)}/f}$